# Use Powershell to list all mailbox users contacts from their contact folder with all attributes

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, office365

I am on Office 365 and I (Admin of the site) have to run a query that takes a users mailbox (e. g: 'john.doe@example.com') and lists all of its contacts from the contact folder with all available attributes like name, email-address and so on. After searching heavily with Google and co. I found nothing regarding powershell handling contacts except importing and exporting. Is there a way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use an API like Exchange Web Services to access that level of information. You can use the EWS Managed API from Powershell. As it turns out, Glen Scales has a [good write-up on exporting contacts that way](http://gsexdev.blogspot.com/2014/02/exporting-contacts-to-csv-file-using.html).